# How can I add a parameter to a HyperLink in WPF?

Tags: wpf, parameters, hyperlink

I have a column in a gridview that has a hyperlink defined in each row.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Click="btn_Authorise">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LinkText}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

I would like the hyperlink to execute different code depending on some parameters I bind to it. ie. the user clicks the link and in the code behind it looks at a parameter and opens one of four dialog windows. How can I add a parameter? Should I be using Commands?

I an new to WPF.

EDIT:

Ok - So all I needed to do was add the CommandParameter="" and I could then handle the rest in the event handler. This is probably not the correct usage of 'Commanding'.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Click="btn_Authorise" CommandParameter="{Binding ActionProperty}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LinkText}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** So apparently Hyperlinks also have commanding, which makes this quite straightforward.

See the [commanding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) if you are new to commands in WPF.

---

You could wrap it in a lookless Button and only handle the Button.Click, then you can bind a Command to it and utilize the CommandParameter.

To make a button lookless you can change the Template:

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

Comment: The HyperLink provides a Command and CommandParameter property - can I just use them?

Comment: I guess my question is really how do I hook up a command? Do I have to make a custom command?

Comment: See the link i provided in my answer, it should help.